# how can I recursively store elements of a Binary Search Tree in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to store elements of a bst in a vector by inorder traversal but it seems only the first element is getting stored in that vector. In the below program I am giving a set of numbers which will form the bst and then I will run inorder recursive calls and store the elements of that bst in the vector, then in the `main()` section I'll sort that vector and then print the Kth smallest number.

**code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
   int data;
   node *left;
   node *right;
};

//inserting the data
node *insert(node *r, int data)
{
   if (r == NULL)
   {
      node *newnode = new node();
      newnode->data = data;
      newnode->left = NULL;
      newnode->right = NULL;
      r = newnode;
   }

   else if (data <= r->data)
   {
      r->left = insert(r->left, data);
   }

   else
   {
      r->right = insert(r->right, data);
   }
   return r;
}

//function to extract the elements from the bst
vector<int> inorder(node *r, vector<int> v)
{
   if (r == NULL)
   {
      return v;
   }
   else
   {
      inorder(r->left, v);
      v.push_back(r->data);
      inorder(r->right, v);
   }

   return v;
}

int main()
{

   vector<int> node_data;
   int entries;
   cout << "enter the number of nodes in the bst::" << endl;
   cin >> entries;
   node *root;
   root = new node();
   root = NULL;
   for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
   {
      int data;
      cin >> data;
      root = insert(root, data);
   }

   vector<int> v = inorder(root, node_data);
   sort(v.begin(), v.end());
   for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   {
      cout << v[i] << " ";
   }
}
```

please help me find the error in the above code so that all the elements of the bst are stored in that vector

Comment: `root = new node();` followed immediately by `root = NULL;` is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

For me the glaring error is that you pass the vector by value (and thus make a copy) and you return the updated vector, but you don't store the return value in `inorder(r->left, v);` and `inorder(r->right, v);`, so you should decide whether you want to pass the result vector by reference instead or to make sure that you handle the result returned by the inorder() function. Passing by reference is more efficient but not always possible if the result changes depending on what branch you're on (e.g. backtracking), but I think that it works for collecting.

Comment: all I want is to store elements of the bst in that vector could you give me a function for that. lets say that function is extract_elements which takes the parameters: 1) root node 2) the vector in which the elements are to be stored

Comment: Your `inorder()` already does that and I pointed out the error why it doesn't work. Is there anything in my answer that is not clear?

Comment: I am not able to get it could you pls type the function and share with me

Comment: No, I have the feeling that you presented the code as if it is yours, but it is actually an assignment and you want somebody else to do your work. I could be wrong...

Comment: @JayantNigam Hints: at each recursive call you have a new `v` vector in `inorder`. The function signature should be `void inorder(node* r, vector<int> & v)`. `sort(v.begin(), v.end());` is pointless because `inorder` already sorts the vector.